# combine multiple rows into one row using one column as guide, then concatenate/join another column's value together into that same row

Tags: python, pandas

Below I have a spreadsheet that is 20K rows strong.  I am trying to use the "ResNum" column only to find exact matches and then combine those rows(however many) into one row.  The catch is each row with the same 'ResNum' has a different value in the "Rate" column.  I need to concatenate or join these different rate values into that single row that we have with a separator( I use a pipe here).

Also, I have 46 more columns that also need to be listed within the final output.

I have edited an extra column within this question to hopefully help.  "Name", & "Nights". Both columns are extra columns to represent other columns within the spreadsheet.  These two columns do not need to be groupby  or agg (as statements mentioned below).  They are columns (along with 46 others) that need to be listed in the final.

Please let me know if you can guide me in the right direction.  I appreciate any time and help with this.

```
import pandas as pd

#--------------------Current Spreadsheet
data = {
       'ResNum':[1001,1001,2002,3003,3003,3003,4004],
       'Name': ['Tom','Tom', 'Nick', 'Krish','Krish','Krish', 'Jack'],
       'Rate':[100.00,101.00,70.00,55.00,56.00,57.00,87.00],
       'Nights':[1,1,1,1,1,1,3]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


#--------------------Results Needed
data2 = {
       'ResNum':[1001,2002,3003,4004],
       'Name': ['Tom', 'Nick', 'Krish', 'Jack'],
       'Rate':['100.00|101.00','70.00','55.00|56.00|57.00','87.00'],
       'Nights':[2,1,3,1]
       }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)


#--------------------Print Area
print('Current Spreadsheet')
print(df)
print('\n')
print('Results needed')
print(df2)
```

Comment: No, each rate represents one night stayed.  Different rates different nights...

Comment: If you have 50 columns, you would need to give an example of how the 50 look before and how you want the df to look after

Comment: @Boomer - In `df2`, the Nights column should be `[1,2,1,3]`

Comment: My apologies stefan_aus_hannover, I was trying to keep this short.  I do not need to groupby the "Name" or the "Nights" columns.  Nights column after edit. But they need to in the output just the same.

Comment: not_speshal......Each rate number represents a night stayed.  In this case, Tom has two rates and stayed two nights.  Krish has three rates and stayed three nights.  Hotels are confusing.....I understand..

Comment: stefan_aus_hannover,   Please let me know if the Name & Nights columns can represent the 46 other extra columns.....If not, I can take the time to put all 49 columns in the test question sample.  You are taking the time to help.  Least I can do....Thanks

Comment: @Boomer not_speshal's solution will get you closer to where you want to be unless you need more aggregation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `join` to the original DataFrame:

```
output = (df.drop(columns="Rate")
          .set_index("ResNum")
          .join(df["Rate"]
                .astype(str)
                .groupby(df["ResNum"])
                .agg("|".join))
          .drop_duplicates()
          .reset_index()
          )

>>> output
   ResNum   Name  Nights            Rate
0    1001    Tom       1     100.0|101.0
1    2002   Nick       2            70.0
2    3003  Krish       1  55.0|56.0|57.0
3    4004   Jack       3            87.0
```

Comment: Read OP's comment on the previous answer. The previous answer specifies one column to aggregate, mine does not. So it would apply to OP's actual dataset of 49+ columns.

Comment: Vitalizzare, stefan_aus_hannover's answer does work with the columns within the test question.  But The output is only the three columns because two are listed within the groupby statement and then the "Rate" is listed for the agg part of the code.....

Comment: The groupby should only be for the ResNum column and then the Rate column be agg together...... Take the "Name column out of the groupby statement and only two columns are outputted......I need all other columns listed within the output.....I hope this makes some sense

Comment: Isn't the combination of `ResNum` and `Name` unique? If so, it doesn't matter if it's in the `groupby`. If not, what do you want as the output for the `Name` column?

Comment: @not_speshal The OP doesn't mention having 50 columns IN their question. And when I gave my answer their was no mention of more than the 3 columns in the question.

Comment: I was just explaining how my answer is different to yours.

Comment: This answer would `agg()` every column not in the `groupby()`

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover - Correct, I misunderstood. Edited.

Comment: Sorry guys,, just trying to read through this and understand.

Comment: @Boomer read the comment I added to your question

Answer (score 3):

This was just similarly answered on another thread. You're looking for `groupby()` with an `agg()` like so

```
import pandas as pd
#--------------------Current Spreadsheet
data = {
   'ResNum':[1001,1001,2002,3003,3003,3003,4004],
   'Name': ['Tom','Tom', 'Nick', 'Krish','Krish','Krish', 'Jack'],
   'Rate':[100.00,101.00,70.00,55.00,56.00,57.00,87.00]
   }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df2 = df.astype('string')
df2 = df2.groupby(['ResNum','Name'])['Rate'].agg('|'.join).reset_index()


df2

    ResNum  Name    Rate
0   1001    Tom     100.0|101.0
1   2002    Nick    70.0
2   3003    Krish   55.0|56.0|57.0
3   4004    Jack    87.0
```

Comment: Hello stefan_aus_hanover, I was able to make your snippet work with a df2 = df.astype('str') vs df.astype('string') in your first line. not sure but maybe just a pycharm/Python 3 thing. What I wanted from the question works with a 50 row test sample, however, I failed to mention that I have 49 columns with this spreadsheet in the above question(I'm sorry for that).  Placing all the header names within the groupby brackets in your 2nd line didn't work. I assume that python is trying to groupby each column and finding differences therefore not colosidating the rows.

Comment: Just so you understand. I only have three columns for the test question you have helped me with above. Just 3 of the 49 columns that I need to show. How would I show all the columns along with the columns we are sorting with in this example?

Comment: Thank You stefan_aus_hannover & not_speshal for taking the time.  I apologize for my lacking on explaining in the original question.  I was able to get all 34K of rows cleaned and data currently is checking out to be good.  I appreciate both of you for helping me.